# Copying very long expression to LaTeX

Tags: simplifying-expressions, latex

I have a long expression (even after using `Simplify`) which I am trying to copy to LaTeX using the "Copy to LaTeX" command. However, it is too messy for LaTeX to handle as is. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do more automatic simplification or a more compact way to export to LaTex?

[image]

Comment: No way without a copyable form of the expression...

Comment: There is no magic. All software has limitations. After looking at your result at full size, I think it is likely that no translation to LaTeX as single expression would be manageable. I believe you need to break the result into a number of much smaller components, assign the components to auxiliary variables and translate the assignment expressions plus the combining expression to LaTeX form individually.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say this @m_goldberg ! :) Yes, I think that seems to be the only solution.

Comment: There are other benefits. Judicious choice of the component structures — made with an understanding of the meaning of the result, which Mathematica certainly does not have — will make your paper much clearer to its readers.

Comment: @Somos. One very good reason is to publish the result in a journal that accepts papers with LaTeX markup.